# Badge Progress: Copy Editor progress showing before Strunk & White

Tags: bug, review-queues, badges

The review queues have a neat little feature, the "Badge Progress":
[image]

Before I had earned the [Reviewer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/1478/reviewer) badge (silver) it showed me the progress with that badge instead of my progress with the [Steward](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/2279/steward) badge (gold). However, it has always been showing me my progress with the [Copy Editor](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/223/copy-editor) badge, which is a gold badge. But there is another silver badge ([Strunk & White](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/12/strunk-white)) which comes before Copy Editor.

I consider this a bug in the badge progress widget - it should probably show the Strunk & White badge progress instead of Copy Editor if Strunk & White hasn't been earned yet.

Comment: You have made a very astute observation and a good point.  How has this not received an answer by now?

Comment: This would increase the enthusiasm in the users to work for more badges and understand their progress in achieving a particular badge. We would also be able to monitor our progress in achieving a particular badge.

The badges monitoring tool should not be visible for all badges. For example the basic badges whereby the badge is awarded in relation to one single post do not need any monitoring. Also, to avoid too much information in this tool, badges in the Tag Badges category should not be listed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can now select a badge to follow, and in the overview of "select a badge" you [see your progress on all trackable badges](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/299809/why-cant-you-see-review-badges-in-your-profile-page-until-youve-earned-them). I think that resolves your issue in that you can opt-in for whatever badge you prefer to track.

[image]