# Can we have a badge progress monitor on the badges page?

Tags: feature-request

I know I can go to the review page and see my stats, and that shows me a funky little badge progress widget, but it only shows my progress towards four badges - Reviewer, Civic Duty, Copy Editor (though as [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251977/badge-progress-copy-editor-progress-showing-before-strunk-white) says it should show Strunk and White anyway), and Electorate.

While it's true that many badges are a simple "do this once" kind of thing, such as Talkative or Quorum, there are some which lend themselves to being "progress monitored" in the same way, such as Pundit, Convention, Outspoken, Enthusiast/Fanatic, Deputy/Marshal.

Could these (and any others which would be "cheap" to implement) have a progress monitor added on the badges page?

Comment: See [Badge progress reports](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/3230)

Comment: @MartijnPieters That's nice as far as it goes, but it's a) one query at a time, b) slow for several of them, and c) reportedly based on old data.

Comment: 'old' here is up to a week old. The dump is refreshed once a week now. But that post is at least *helpful* if you want to look at progress right now.

Comment: OK, I didn't know how old was "old", so thank you for that. And yes, it's helpful in the short term. I'm still after a "single click, at a glance" solution if it's feasible. I'm also fully aware that some of the queries would be prohibitively expensive to do in that fashion, so limited my question to the ones which would be "cheap" (in server/query terms) to provide.

Comment: It would be nice though ...

Comment: This would increase the enthusiasm in the users to work for more badges and understand their progress in achieving a particular badge. We would also be able to monitor our progress in achieving a particular badge.

The badges monitoring tool should not be visible for all badges. For example the basic badges whereby the badge is awarded in relation to one single post do not need any monitoring. Also, to avoid too much information in this tool, badges in the Tag Badges category should not be listed.

Comment: @MicheleLaFerla ... while on the other hand the progress for Tag Badges would be especially interesting. Because the gold badge comes with a moderator ability that is unlocked.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I check how close I am to win Announcer, Booster or Publicist badge?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/311206/how-do-i-check-how-close-i-am-to-win-announcer-booster-or-publicist-badge)

Comment: @BartłomiejSemańczyk How can a question which was asked 18 months ago "already have an answer" on a question which was asked only a week ago? The duplication, if duplication it is, is the other way around.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has now been delivered in the "Next badge" popup from the new user profiles (under Activity, Badges), which lets you see them all but also lets you choose a particular one as your personal "next target".

Answer (score 0):

I'd ***really love*** to see a column added to the [Unearned badges](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges?tab=General&filter=unearned) page, with a progressbar in it next to each badge, that looks like these:

[image]

Comment: This page is an old feature request that was implemented nearly five years ago. If you have a new feature request, you should probably ask it as a new question, so it can attract the right kind of attention and responses.

Comment: @IMSoP Really? Visit your unearned badges page and show me those progressbars. I already know about the "next badge" tracker, which is nothing like what I just requested. If I post this as a new question people will just point to this post and recommend deleting mine as a "duplicate".

Comment: The "next badge" tracker may not be what _you_ were requesting, but it is what _this question_ was requesting, as evidenced by the accepted answer saying "this has now been delivered". So your question would not be a duplicate, because you're requesting a new feature, not the existing feature discussed on this page.