# Progress bar for badges

Tags: discussion, feature-request, badges

Most Stack Exchange sites offer a progress bar that displays how much reputation one needs to earn the next privilege.

Would it be a good idea to display a progress bar for some of the badges as well? For example, for the "Pundit" badge, one needs to post 10 comments with a score of 5 or more. Why not add a progress bar that displays how many more comments are needed to earn this badge? Would this be a relatively expensive feature to implement?

There are a number of other badges where such a feature seems useful. I believe this will add to the quality of the site.

Comment: Some badges have this - you can see that in the review queues. I believe it is quite expensive to commute, so it is used sparingly.

Comment: There's a plan for this to be part of the profile page redesign. Jarrod & Nick are working on this now. Not exactly a *progress bar* as such, more of a "you're *thiiiiis* close to your next badge" thing.

Comment: Duplicate of http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/256050/can-we-have-a-badge-progress-monitor-on-the-badges-page

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You'll find that this is already implemented for some badges. If you go to the review queue and click on the green bar next to your number of reviews, a small window pops up:

[image]

I would love to see more of these, but I'm sure they have their reasons to not add this for every badge - it's probably expensive to be calling the data for every user so much.

You can get around this using the [StackExchange data explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/). For example, this query tells you how close you are to getting the Unsung Hero badge:

https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/7521/how-unsung-am-i

My suggestion would be for that Badge Progress popup in the screenshot to replace completed badges with new badges that aren't earned yet, so you can always track the progress of new badges once you complete those three.

Comment: What if you are a low-rep usesr like me? How can you see your progress then? @AlexK

Comment: @Player72 I'm sorry, you can't. With the new profile design that is going to be released soon, you should be able to though!

Comment: I have been reading up on that, and I will be waiting for the shiny profile page!