# Is there a way to see my progress towards a specific "reviewer" badge?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, badges

I already have two reviewer badges, one for first posts, one for triage.

Is there a way to see how many "Late Answers" reviews I've made?

Comment: Not asking the same question, but has the same answer here: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284517/progress-bar-for-badges

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.

Go to the review queue you wish to check progress for. In the upper right corner of the page, you should see some tabs such as "stats", "history", and "review". Before these tabs, there will be a number and a partially green/grey bar. The number is your number of reviews for that queue.

Hover over this bar and you'll see a breakdown of the "Reviewer" badge for that queue, along with a couple other badges.

[image: Reviewer badge tracker]

For example, this is what I see for the "Triage" review queue.