# How do I check how close I am to win Announcer, Booster or Publicist badge?

Tags: support, feature-request, badges

I shared some links to some posts and now I would like to know what is the progress. Is there a way to check this shortly?

Comment: In "Activity" tab there's "Next badge" indicator. If you click the small icon ("Choose which badge to track") next to it, can't you see those badges in the list?

Comment: @Teemu, no you can't.

Comment: If I remember correctly this question was already being asked and there is no such feature. One of posted in that duplicate (I can't find it now) ways around would be using some external site which will generate link which will redirect it to your site/link. Such site should also count number of clicks.

Comment: if this is a feature request in itself, I guess the answer bu Undo should be unaccepted - or maybe preferrably another post should be created in the form of a feature request.

Comment: I'm pretty sure there a lots more badges than the ones in the title that you can't see in the "Track next badge" menu.

Comment: Of course, there is a lot more badges you cant track as a "next", but these ones are important and exclusive for some people:)

Comment: 5-year-old FR on MSE: [View progress towards Announcer, Booster, and Publicist badges](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/67240/134300)

Comment: It is duplicated question, and you have to deal with it. Sorry. Progress in that badges is in fact number of views question via link, as there. Do not scream in your post, just because you don't agree. Please. And duplication of duplicated question is still duplication.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

I don't believe this information is exposed anywhere. You could post a [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) for this to be implemented - I'd be curious to see this kind of information too.