# Epic and Legendary 200 daily reputation: how to check

Tags: feature-request, badges, daily-reputation-badges

The [epic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/145/epic) and the [Legendary](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/146/legendary) badges for earning 200 daily reputation are very hard to achieve.

It would be nice to have a recap in the profile page to check quickly how many times this target was be achieved.

In my opinion it would be nice to have **intermediate targets as 10,25,40,100**.

Comment: They're deliberately meant to be hard to achieve... If you go to http://stackoverflow.com/reputation and go down to the bottom - you can see how often you've rep-capped...

Comment: Nice recap, I didn't know it. However it is right to have hard targets, may be it would be nice to have intermediate targets.

Comment: Guess it's time to introduce *diamond* badges :D

Comment: Also the [Research Assistant](http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/1656/research-assistant) badge is awarded only 227 times and it's silver.

Comment: @BhargavRao: [We have that already](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/3109/sheriff) :P

Comment: @KevinGuan That is gold badge to *diamond* people :D

Comment: @BhargavRao: Yeah, and see, only *diamond* people have the **Sheriff** badge :P

Comment: @jonrsharpe It is not a full duplicate question. I am also proposing some intermediate steps and I am asking how to check this target on own profile.

Comment: And that's why you should ask one question at a time.

Comment: In any case the real topic is not about the difficulty to achieve the badge (because it is not a question but a fact), but how to check on own profile and there is a right answer below.

Comment: Which was also already available, see e.g. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/290433/3001761

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To view progress, the preferred method is to use your profile page where you will see under the "Activity" tab something similar to:

[image]

Click the cog to change the target to the badge you wish to track - eg: "Epic" / "Legendary" for instance.