# Why can't you see review-badges in your profile-page until you've earned them?

Tags: support, feature-request, review-queues, badges, profile-page

I want to track my progress for a review-badge on my profile-page. Why can't the "next badge" progress-bar be used to track review badges as well as other ones?

I've earned the "Custodian" badge, and I can see it in the "select your next badge" dialog-box. I can't see review-badges that I haven't earned in the dialog-box, though.

> [image: The "Reviewer" badge is missing!]

People have to go to the review queues, select a queue, and go to the "stats" tab to see their badge-progress.

When users have reviewed 20 posts in a day for a queue, the link to the queue is grayed-out, so they can't access the "stats" tab to track their badges for that queue.

> [image: Unable to access review-queue "stats!"]

If users can track review-badges on their profile-page, it'd be more convenient.

It'd also be more consistent because review-badges are badges too, right? Stack Overflow lets you chose moderation-badges, answer-badges, and participation-badges as your "next badge," so why not review-badges?

Since review-badges are awarded once per review queue, they can either add additional UI elements, or have variants of the same review-badges, such as "Custodian (Triage)" and "Steward (Late-Answers)."

Comment: The 'recent reviews' link (partially visible in your last screenshot) will also bring you to the "stats" tab.

Comment: It would be nice to see these trackable, I don't see why they couldn't list the multiple possibilities of the same badges. Maybe if more people bump this post we can convince them.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The other ones don't show up because it would require additional UI to choose *which* review queue you want to track, unless you're proposing that it just always select the one nearest to completion. But then you wouldn't be able to use the tracker if you've already earned one for any queue, because it would always attempt to select one that's completed. So either way, it would require quite a bit more coding to make that a reality.

All the badges present in those lists are things you can only earn one of, so there's only one count that the system needs to track. There are plenty of other non-review badges that can be awarded multiple times that aren't available in that list, and even some special ones that you can only earn once (such as Talkative and Outspoken) which aren't available.

The exception is made for Custodian because it only requires doing *one* so there's not anything to track other than "yay you went to a review queue and did something", and bronze badges are generally used to educate users about the features of our site (basically a note that says "hey, check out the review queues"). I'll also note that the silver and gold review badges do not ever appear in that list, even if you have earned one.

This isn't declined right now - it might be something we'd consider in the future. I'm just explaining why it's not there right now. For now, you can always click the "recent reviews" link under the avatars at the right, which will take you to the stats page for that queue which has the progress bar on it (in the same place).

Comment: "All the badges present in those lists are things you can only earn one of"... That's not entirely true; the Revival and Necromancer badges are present in the list of badges to track, and those can be earned multiple times.

Comment: "would require additional UI to choose which review queue you want to track, unless you're proposing that it just always select the one nearest to completion." Why not just include them all, even at the risk of having duplicates? Also, I don't understand how this change would be prohibitive in terms of code complexity...it's already the case that a store is queried and results are shown.

Comment: By the way, same thing applies to "Unsung Hero". It is not visible in the list of selection; however, it is visible in the [bagde's list in the help article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges). What's the reason of this?